# Check Parse duplicates (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have a class on Parse.com that have a "GeoPoint" column (every object has longitude and latitude).

I want to check if there are two objects with the same GeoPoint.

I've tried this but it's not working (printing objects that don't have duplicates):

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Schools"];
query.limit=1000;
[self.myObjects addObjectsFromArray:[[query findObjects] mutableCopy]];

NSMutableArray *geoPoints=[NSMutableArray array];
for (PFObject *object in self.myObjects) {
    [geoPoints addObject:[object objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"]];
}

NSCountedSet *cs=[[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:geoPoints];

int num=1;
for (PFObject *object in cs) {
    if ([cs countForObject:object]>1) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",[[self.myObjects objectAtIndex:num] objectForKey:@"Name"], [[self.myObjects objectAtIndex:num] objectForKey:@"Address"]);
        num++;
    }
}
```

How can I check duplicates on NSArray/Parse itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to know about duplicates? How are you adding the two points in the first place? Why don't you have cloud code to check for dupes on save if they're an issue?

Comment: @Wain The user don't add objects to Parse (the app just fetches the data I prepared in advanced) so it needs to be a one-time event, that's why I don't have a cloud code. I'm showing markers on a map for each school and if there is two schools with the same geoPoint one marker will be on top of the other so I want to find the objects that has another school with the same geoPoint and move it a bit to the side and that will solve my problem. I need to know how to find these duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach. As you zoom a map in and out pins that are far apart will start to overlap. As a result you should have a general soliton for this problem (instead of editing the source data).

The approach to take is called map pin clustering. Whenever the map zoom / pins are updated an algorithm runs to determine which pins are close together and should be grouped. This results in one pin on the map backed by multiple original pins (annotations). When the pin is selected you can show the information for all the annotations.

There are a number of implementations of this that you can use: [mkmapview pin clustering](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Mkmapview+pin+clustering)

Comment: The markers hide each other so it's not the solution, the bottom marker will never be visible so I need to change the data, unfortunately.
By the way, I need this thing too for arrange my map so, is there a similar thing for GMSMapView?